# How do I get input from an Html file and output in another HTML file

Tags: jquery, html

**First HTML file**:

I have a simple input tag in a form that asks the user to type anything(*text*) he wants.

**Second HTML file**:

Accesses the input inside the form in first HTML file and prints it three times.

**First HTML**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
     <head>
        <title>First HTML</title>
     </head>
     <body>
        <form>
           input <input id="silly" type="text" placeholder="Enter something silly">
       </form>
     </body>
</html>
```

**Second HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
      <head>
         <title>Second HTML</title>
      </head>
      <body>
         <p id="printHere">print the input here 3 times</p>
      </body>
   </html>
```

***The JQuery I'm trying to use in second HTML***

```
$.get('a.html', null, function(text){
    alert($(text).find('.silly'));
});
```

Comment: you can use `cookies`, `web storage` etc to mimmic data passing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
     <head>
        <title>First HTML</title>
     </head>
     <body>
        <form>
           input <input id="silly" type="text" placeholder="Enter something silly" value="aa">
       </form>
     </body>
</html>
```

Second HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
     <title>Second HTML</title>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajax({ 
        url: 'first.html', 
        dataType: 'html', 
        success: function(response) { 
            $(response).find('#silly').clone().appendTo("#printHere");
            $(response).find('#silly').clone().appendTo("#printHere");
            $(response).find('#silly').clone().appendTo("#printHere");
        } 
    });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
     <p id="printHere">print the input here 3 times</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps. Thanks

Comment: If it really helped you, please give an up vote. Thanks :-)